# mysqli_stmt::num_rows() returns the wrong value

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was writing a database handler class in PHP using the mysqli class and prepared statements.  I was attempting to print out the result.  It didn't work right off the bat so I decided to do some debugging.  I tried to use the `num_rows()` method from the `mysqli_statement` class, but it kept returning 0.  I decided to write a small portion of the test code to keep it simpler so I could see what was going wrong.  I was then able to return the data I wanted, but the `num_rows()` method still returns 0 even when it is actually selecting and retrieving some data.  Here is the code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  die('connection failed');
}

$statement = $mysqli->stmt_init();

$query = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE id = '2000'";
if($statement->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($name);
    $statement->fetch();
    $statement->store_result();
    echo $statement->num_rows();
    echo $name; 
}
else
{
    echo 'prepare statement failed';
    exit();
}
```

The expected result is:

```
1name
```

And the actual result is:

```
0name
```

Can anyone tell me why this is?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wonder if num_rows() is reporting relative to the current resultset. Try capturing num_rows() prior to fetching the data. e.g.

```
if($statement->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    echo $statement->num_rows();
    $statement->bind_result($name);
    $statement->fetch();
    echo $name; 
}
```

Does that have any effect?

Comment: Indeed, this was the problem.  In order for num_rows() to return the right value, store_result() must be called before fetch().

Comment: That's what I figured; fetching the data increments the internal row counter, so that you can do something like while( $statement->num_rows() ) { /* do stuff */ }

Comment: I strongly believe that @StevenOxley's comment IS the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

`num_rows` is not a method, it's a property.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to use `mysqli_stmt::num_rows(),` you need to fetch all rows into PHP. There are two ways to fetch everything: buffering using `store_result()` or manual fetching of all rows using `fetch()`.

In your case, you have started manual fetching by calling `fetch()` once. You can't call `store_result()` when another fetch process is ongoing. The call to `store_result()` fails with an error*.

```
$statement->fetch();
$statement->store_result(); // produces error. See $mysqli->error;
echo $statement->num_rows();
```

The easiest solution is to swap the order in which you call these two methods.

```
$statement->store_result();
$statement->fetch(); // This will initiate fetching from PHP buffer instead of MySQL buffer
echo $statement->num_rows(); // This will tell you the total number of rows fetched to PHP
```

<sub>* Due to a bug in PHP, this error will not trigger an exception in the exception error reporting mode. The error message can only be seen with `mysqli_error()` function or its corresponding property.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't look like you've declared $name.

Also, try removing bind_result() and fetch() so it reads something like this:

```
$statement->execute();

$statement->store_result();

printf("Number of rows: %d.\n", $statement->num_rows);
```