# mysqli num_rows returning 0

Tags: php, mysqli

Can not figure out why this is not working.  Have gone through other questions here, but it seems my code is fine.

```
$queryLink = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vendor_name FROM vendors WHERE vendor_id='1'");
$queryLink->execute();
$queryLink->store_result;
$queryLink->bind_result($vendor_name);
$queryLink->fetch();
$numRows = $queryLink->num_rows;
$queryLink->close();

echo $vendor_name.'<br>'.$numRows;
```

The script returns this:

```
VendorNameHere
0
```

It is returning 1 record, but $numRows always stays 0.  I have tried moving the numRows line to different places in the script, but it always returns 0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure about your query? `vendor_name FROM vendors WHERE vendor_id='1'` and not `vendor_name FROM vendors WHERE vendor_name='1'` ? depending on what your column's name is.

Comment: column names are correct... it even returns the one record it binded.  However, num_rows stays at 0.

Comment: Try this instead `$numRows = $queryLink->num_rows();`

Comment: and also `$queryLink->store_result();` you left out `()` in both lines.

Comment: @Fred-ii- $stmt::num_rows is a property, not a method.

Comment: So this http://stackoverflow.com/a/80400/1415724 on SO is an incorrect answer then ? @MikeW

Comment: @Fred-ii- Indeed it is - read down the answers.

Comment: I'm just wondering why that answer got accepted in the first place @MikeW Live 'n Learn, I will ;-) thanks Mike and I'll make a note of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
$queryLink->store_result;
```

Should be a method call:

```
$queryLink->store_result();
```

Comment: That did it.  Stupid typo, as always.  Thank you.

Comment: one of the comments that I said ;-)

Comment: `+1` for you Mike, I appreciate the added info ;-)

Answer (score 0):

But you don't need number of rows here. Apparently there will be only one vendor with such id. Why bloat your code with useless function calls?

```
$id   = 1;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vendor_name FROM vendors WHERE vendor_id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($vendor_name);
$stmt->fetch();

if ($vendor_name) {
    echo $vendor_name;
} else {
    echo "None found";
}
```

is all the code you need.