# Cannot retrieve data from database. Number of rows=0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this block of code that is supposed to be used to authenticate a user on login. If i try supplying an email address and password that exists in the database, i get the error message in $loginerror. I don't get any error, but my code doesn't seem to get any result set, as when i try to echo `$stmt->num_rows` it's prints out 0. Please what am i doing wrong?

Here's the code block:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['signin'])){
    require_once "logincheck.php";

    $signin_email=$_POST['signin_email'];
    $signin_password=$_POST['signin_password'];

if($valid){
        require_once 'scripts/connect_to_mysql.php';     

        $sql ="SELECT First_name, Last_name FROM customer WHERE Email=? AND Password=?";
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);//preparing the statement
        if(!$stmt){
            echo "Unable to prepare: ".$conn->errno. " " .$conn->error;
        }
        //executing the statement
        //$date=date('d m Y h:i:s');
        if(!$stmt->bind_param('ss', $signin_email, $signin_password)){//bind parameters to sql statement. i=integer, s=string, b=blob, d=double 
            echo "Binding parameters failed: ".$stmt->errno. " " . $stmt->error;
        }
        if(!$stmt->execute()){//executing the statement
            echo "Statement Execution failed: ". $stmt->error;
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_result($firstname,$lastname)){// used to bind variables to a prepared statement for result storage
            echo "Unable to bind results to variables: ".$stmt->error;
        }
        //echo $stmt->num_rows;
        if($stmt->num_rows===1){//to check if username and password actually exists
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $user=$firstname. " ". $lastname;
            echo $user;
        }
        $_SESSION['user']=$user;
        header('location:logintest.php');
        exit();
        }
        else{

            $loginerror= "Invalid Email address/Password. Please try again";
        }
        $stmt->close();//closing the prepared statement
        $conn->close();//closing the connection

}

}
?>
```

Comment: why `Email=?` amd same for password?

Comment: Where's this code `$valid` ?

Comment: This won't solve your problem but may help youin the future : you should NEVER store plain-text passwords in your database. This is a huge security gap. Now, back to your problem, to debug you would need to check where the problem occurs : is the user correctly inserted in the database ? Are you sure the name the POST variables are correct ?

Comment: @user123 I'm using prepared statements

Comment: @Tuga It's in the logincheck.php file.

Comment: @Bartdude I'm actually just using this to check, ofcourse i'd need to encrypt my password. The user is correctly inserted in the database, infact i tried using different users, same problem and yes the post variables are correct.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20014621/285587 and many, many, many others

Comment: @YourCommonSense I've gone through some of them and they don't solve my problem.

Comment: I am sorry, you gone through some of *what*?

Comment: @YourCommonSense some of the questions related to mine.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so i was able to resolve this by adding `$stmt->store_result()` to my code. So now i have,

```
if(!$stmt->bind_result($firstname,$lastname)){// used to bind variables to a prepared statement for result storage
            echo "Unable to bind results to variables: ".$stmt->error;
        }

        $stmt->store_result();

        if($stmt->num_rows===1){//to check if username and password actually exists
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            $user=$firstname. " ". $lastname;
            echo $user;
        }
```

in place of :

```
if(!$stmt->bind_result($firstname,$lastname)){// used to bind variables to a prepared statement for result storage
                echo "Unable to bind results to variables: ".$stmt->error;
            }

            if($stmt->num_rows===1){//to check if username and password actually exists
            while($stmt->fetch()){
                $user=$firstname. " ". $lastname;
                echo $user;
            }
```

According to the [PHP Manual here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php), you need to add `store_result()` for you to get `num_rows` to work.

Comment: 'according to the linked answer' surely you wanted to say.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using MySQL, PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows in the result set.

For other databases/MySQL, you can

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
$rowCount = count($rows);
```

Comment: because this answer has nothing to do with question.